# SQL: Looking at Bundle of Products Sold

Tags: sql

I have a sample DB below. I'm looking to see how many TV and Internet bundles we sold. In the sample data, only Bob and Trevor sold that bundle so we sold 2.

How do I write the query for the number of bundles sold by each Sales rep and the total price of the bundles sold?

Thanks

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Please show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Please do not use images but put the information into your question.  Thanks.

Comment: For a bundle to happen, does the same sales person needs to have sold both products to the *same* customer?

Comment: Hi @HereGoes understood! Will do for my future inquiries.

 For a bundle it has to be sold to the same person.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply group the salesman's by counting the distinct products they sold -

```
SELECT Sales_Person, FLOOR(COUNT(DISTINCT product_name)/2) NO_OF_BUNDLES, sum(total_price)
FROM YOUR_TAB
WHERE product_name IN ('TV', 'Internet')
GROUP BY Sales_Person
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_name) >= 2
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, this shows me the total persons per sales rep but how about the number of bundles?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that, for a bundle to happen, the same sales person needs to have sold both products to the *same customer*.

I would approach this with two levels of aggregation. First group by sales person and customer in a subquery to identify the bundles, then, in an outer query, count how many such bundles happened for each sales person:

```
SELECT sales_person, COUNT(*) bundles_sold, SUM(total_price) total_price
FROM (
    SELECT sales_person, customer_name, SUM(total_price) total_price
    FROM mytable
    WHERE product_name in ('TV', 'Phone')
    GROUP BY sales_person
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_name) = 2
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Using cte as below:

```
with cte1(sales_person, customer_name, product_count) as
(
select sales_person, customer_name, count(product_name)
from sales
where product_name in ('TV', 'Internet')
group by sales_person, customer_name
having count(product_name) = 2
)
select sales_person, count(product_count)
from cte1
group by sales_person
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two levels of aggregation:

```
select sales_person, count(*), sum(total_price)
from (select sales_person, customer_name,
             sum(total_price) as total_price,
             max(case when product_name = 'tv' then 1 else 0 end) as has_tv,
             max(case when product_name = 'phone' then 1 else 0 end) as has_phone,
             max(case when product_name = 'internet' then 1 else 0 end) as has_internet
      from t
      group by sales_person, customer_name
     ) sc
where has_phone = 0 and 
      has_tv = 1 and
      has_internet = 1
group by sales_person;
```

I recommend this structure because it is pretty easy to change the conditions in the `where` clause to return this for any bundle -- or even to aggregate by the three flags and return the totals for all bundles in one query.